# C# WinForm Menu Strip

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, master-pages, menustrip

I m use to ASP.NET with masterpage and session. i put the menu in masterpage. After sucsessfuly login i save the variable in session.

Now i m working with Winform.
the Session i replace with variable
and the master page i replace with Form

so after succsseuly login i save in the variable insted of Session and use the menu strip to switch off and on the panel.

```
public partial class Principale : Form
    static string _ClientId;
    public static string ClientId
    {
        get { return _ClientId; }
        set { _ClientId = value; }
    }


    LeOrdre_BL oOrdre_BL = new LeOrdre_BL();
    LeOrdreStatut_Entite_BL oOrdreStat_BL = new LeOrdreStatut_Entite_BL();

    public Principale()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        ClientId = LoginData.Trim().Substring(0, LoginData.Trim().Length - 1);
        panelControl_Ordre.Hide();
        panelControl_Mag.Hide();
    }

    private void ordreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelControl_Ordre.Show();
        panelControl_Mag.Hide();
        GetDataOrdre();            
    }

    private void magasinierToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelControl_Ordre.Hide();
        panelControl_Mag.Show();            
    }

    public void GetDataOrdre()
    {
        try
        {

            bindingSource_OdreStatus.DataSource = oOrdreStat_BL.Get_All_OrdreStatut();
            STATUT_ORDRE.DataSource = bindingSource_OdreStatus;
            STATUT_ORDRE.DisplayMember = "LIBELLE";
            STATUT_ORDRE.ValueMember = "NO";



            bindingSource_Ordre.DataSource = oOrdre_BL.Get_Ordre_BL();               
            dataGridView_ordre.DataSource = bindingSource_Ordre;
            dataGridView_ordre.DataMember = "OrdreTable";

        }
        catch (Exception excThrown)
        {
            lbl_Princ_Err.Text = excThrown.Message;
        }
    }
```

Am i in the right way to do this or Do you have another idea to replace ASP.NET Masterpage in Winform ?

Thanx in advance

Comment: This works fine if you want to keep your panels in the same form, but are you sure it wouldn't be better to open a new form instead of changing the content of the `Principale` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an MdiContainer. The user state could be stored as a variable in the form that is the mdi container?

Comment: Thanx for your response. 
Now i m using MDIContainer. My new question are:
1. How can i pass the varaible from parent to child ?
2.How can i prohibited to open more than 1 window with the same Name (That means in my MenuStrip there are Ordre,Tarif,Config... when user already open the Ordre, when he click again it not open a new window/created a new child but pointed to the ordre window that already open) ?
Thanx before....

Comment: When you create the child form, make the child form take parameters...  for example in the the mdi container... var customerForm = new CustomerForm(foo, bar); customerForm.Show(); For more info take a look through this documentation... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76(v=vs.80).aspx